# Use first param in django URL

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to to know if its possible to use the first "segment" of a Django URL as a parameter and what would that regex look like.

example:

```
(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
#### I want to use the following
(r'^THISISMYPARAM$, include("whatever")),
```

So then when someone visited http://example.com/SOMETHING I could use do something with that.

My regex keeps breaking my other urls :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
(r'^(?P<thisismyparam>\w+)$', include('whatever'))
```

Comment: Thats the ticket! Once again I realize I need to spend more time with regex. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that all the views included in the 'whatever' urlpatterns should receive 'thisismyparam' as first parameter.

Comment: @jj I thought that the power of naming your parameters was that you could place it as a keyword argument anywhere you want?